# Creating barcode using pylatex

Tags: python, pylatex

I'm trying to create a python program that creates numerous pdfs each containing a unique barcode using `pylatex`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Here is an example of how the latex document is being generated using `pylatex`:

```
with doc.create(MiniPage(width=r"\textwidth")) as page:
   with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 0)):
      page.append("**** Ten Thousand Dollars")

   with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 30)):
      page.append("COMPANY NAME")
      page.append("\nSTREET, ADDRESS")

   with page.create(TextBlock(100, 150, 40)):
      page.append()

   with page.create(TextBlock(80, 150, 0)):
      page.append("DATE")
      page.append(MediumText(bold("test")))
      page.append(HorizontalSpace("10mm"))

   with page.create(TextBlock(70, 150, 30)):
      page.append(MediumText(bold("$***** 10,000.00")))

   page.append(VerticalSpace("100mm"))

   doc.generate_pdf(doc_location, clean_tex=False)
```

I would like to figure out a way to append a barcode to the page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Option one is to generate the barcode as an image using python and include it in the final output. For that if your question is on how to generate the barcode image itself, this would be the wrong forum (it would be a python question). // Option two is to use one of the barcode generating packages available to LaTeX, you can find a list of them on CTAN https://www.ctan.org/topic/barcode Perhaps they can be made to work with pylatex.

Comment: @WillieWong How would you use the barcode generating packages from within ```pylatex```? I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish this

Comment: Try following the examples in https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/own_commands_ex.html and create pylatex versions of the commands that you will need. (FWIW: I know exactly nothing about pylatex until 3 minutes ago.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code you included doesn't seem to produce the expected output, perhaps it is just my settings or I have not used it correctly. Regardless, please see this code which implements the `makebarcode` package and prints a barcode:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pylatex import Document, Command, Package, MiniPage, TextBlock, MediumText, HorizontalSpace, VerticalSpace
from pylatex.utils import bold

def main():

    paper_size = "b5paper"
    geometry_options = {"paper": paper_size, "top": "1.5cm", "bottom": "1.5cm"}

    #------------------- Change barcode package options here --------------------------#
    makebarcode_options = {"code":"Code39", "X":".5mm", "ratio":"2.25","H": "1cm"}
    doc = Document('Testing', geometry_options=geometry_options)

    #------------------- Change barcode package here if you don't want makebarcode --------------------------#
    doc.packages.append(Package('makebarcode', options=makebarcode_options))

    with doc.create(MiniPage(width=r"\textwidth")) as page:
       with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 0)):
          page.append("**** Ten Thousand Dollars")

       with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 30)):
          page.append("COMPANY NAME")
          page.append("\nSTREET, ADDRESS")

       with page.create(TextBlock(100, 150, 40)):
          page.append("Test")

       with page.create(TextBlock(80, 150, 0)):
          page.append("DATE")
          page.append(MediumText(bold("test")))
          page.append(HorizontalSpace("10mm"))

       with page.create(TextBlock(70, 150, 30)):
          page.append(MediumText(bold("$***** 10,000.00")))
          page.append(VerticalSpace("100mm"))

    #------- Change bracket string to something random for unique barcodes ----------#
    doc.append(Command('barcode',["ZDENEK WAGNER"]))

    doc.generate_pdf(filepath=your_path_CHANGE, clean=True, clean_tex=False)
    doc.generate_tex()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This produces this broken output, I am not sure why but the code you included is not compiling properly:

[image]

I am sure you can debug why it is not working, I do not know and cannot profess to great knowledge of python, pylatex or latex as I am still learning! It produces your barcode though, you can change the string (ZDENEK WAGNER in this case which was the one from the `makebarcode` package documentation) to something random, I am sure this is trivial in python to create random or pseudorandom strings.

Change the package options (makebarcode_options has been set according to the `makebarcode` package documentation on page 2, have a look and change as needed) and or package in the places I have commented using the ctan link that Willie Wong posted in the comments if you wish. Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me thank you