# How to use \psbarcode in pylatex

Tags: pylatex, barcodes

Is there a way to use the `\psbarcode` package in `pylatex`? I want to generate several pdfs with unique barcode but I am unsure of how to use the package.

For reference here is how the pdfs are generated using `pylatex`:

```
with doc.create(MiniPage(width=r"\textwidth")) as page:
   with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 0)):
      page.append("**** Ten Thousand Dollars")

   with page.create(TextBlock(100, 0, 30)):
      page.append("COMPANY NAME")

   with page.create(TextBlock(80, 150, 0)):
      page.append(MediumText(bold("test")))

   doc.generate_pdf(doc_location, clean_tex=False)
```

Comment: See the answer to your other question and change the package from "makebarcode" to "psbarcode" and change the options as appropriate in the places my answer showed you, hope it helps. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612259/creating-barcode-using-pylatex

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor thank you